# Three.js lines disappear when partially outside of view in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using Three.js to display a grid using the GridHelper class. The grid lines disappear when the camera is zoomed in and the lines are partially outside of the view. The issue is only present in Chrome, while it works correctly in Firefox. I've tried disabling frustum culling for the grid by setting `frustumCulled = false` and traversing through the children of the grid and setting `frustumCulled = false` for each object, but it doesn't seem to help.

Here is a jsfiddle link to show the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/dc43n91a/

Here is a screenshot how it looks in Firefox (correctly):

[image: Correct behaviour in Firefox]

and Chrome (incorrectly)

[image: Some lines disappear in Chrome]

Here is the code causing the issue:

```
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, 1, 0.1, 1000 );

        scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x333333 );

        camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
        camera.position.set( - 10, - 25, 10 );
        camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
        scene.add( camera );
        
        const grid = new THREE.GridHelper(200, 12);
        grid.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, 0);
        grid.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        grid.frustumCulled = false;
        grid.traverse((object) => { object.frustumCulled = false; });
        grid.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
        scene.add(grid);

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( 400, 400 );

        document.getElementById('viewer').appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Could anyone please help me understand why this issue is happening only in some browsers and how to fix it?

Comment: I have tested your fiddle with Chrome 109.0.5414.87 on macOS and can't reproduce.  What OS and version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @Mugen87 Thank you for your comment. I have tested the code in other environments and also couldn't reproduce the issue. However, I am still concerned about deploying the code into production. I'd like to figure out what could cause the incorrect behaviour. I appreciate any suggestions or advice on how to troubleshoot this further.